# Parse a php file from an outside server

Tags: php, apache, server-side

I'm trying to figure out how (if possible) to do this:

I want to have a server/space/cloud-storage without apache storing a php file, then, another server actually running and parsing that file.

This is because I know Dropbox (Copy, Google Deive, etc) does store any type of file but cannot run php files due to security and due to the lack of Apache.

I therefore thought it may be possible to have a server requesting the Dropbox php file, parse it and return the HTML result.

I thought of this solution and I tried making an include from an external source:

```
include_once("https://dropbox.com/whatever/file.php");
```

But is not feasible... Any solution?

Comment: Why not use dropbox (or any other service) api to load the file and then parse it?

Comment: @JA ok, can you be more specific on this? Perhaps is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: According to the api, https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php you can download and store the file in a variable and then manipulate.

Answer (score 3):

Use the API of Dropbox instead of the webview. Then store the value in a variable or temp file and output the result of `eval($codeFromDropbox);` and delete it if you don't need it anymore.

Dropbox provides you a [PHP class](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php) (also see the [reference](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/)) to archive this or you can simply use the global [HTTP API Docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET) to write this small script on your own.

Once you did the authorization as described in the API docs you can simply download any file you have the permissions for.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually include remote files but it is disabled by default:

http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true);
```

This is OFF (`false`) by default because it is a VERY HIGH security risk.

It's also a high security risk using `eval()`. The whole idea is risky.

Why don't you store and the files on the PHP server you want to execute?

**Update:**

The ini configuration is `allow_url_include`, not `allow_url_fopen`, but you should lookup both.